# how can set gesture event in android on Text View

Tags: android, gesture

I have try to set gesture event on text view. i want to access left to right and right to left   event on text view. same like touch event. i have text view and i want to set event on it. i have also [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) this example but not working on text view. can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your on View and implement a TouchListener there.